# Criar elemento com "onclick()"

Tags: javascript

Preciso criar um elemento com Javascript que, quando clicado, chame uma função.

Existe algum evento que eu possa adicionar ao meu código para isso ? Seria igual ao `onclick()` que colocamos dentro de uma tag html.

Segue o código

```
let inputExc = document.createElement('i') //cria
inputExc.className = 'fas fa-trash-alt ml-2' //define class
inputExc.title = 'Excluir' //define title
inputExc.id = 'iExcluir' //define id
```

Comment: Que tal o `onclick`?

Comment: O onclick funcionou, obrigado. Porém tive que chamar a função no momento que faço a atribuição, dessa forma: "inputExc.onclick = function removerItem(){}"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você deve utilizar o próprio próprio `onclick`.

```js
//método do evento
let clickLixeira = function () { 
  console.log('Clicou na lixeira');
}

let inputExc = document.createElement('i') //cria
inputExc.className = 'fas fa-trash-alt ml-2' //define class
inputExc.title = 'Excluir' //define title
inputExc.id = 'iExcluir' //define id

// bind do evento com o método
inputExc.onclick = clickLixeira;

//adicionando o elemento na tela
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(inputExc);
```

```css
@import 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css';
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Dessa forma funcionou sem problemas, muito obrigado! Porém acho que o código fica meio que "bagunçado" dessa forma, não tem como ao invés de eu abrir chaves, chamar uma função ?

Comment: Claro, você só precisa prestar atenção no escopo de onde você vai declarar esse método, veja a minha edição.

Comment: Beleza Leandro, muito obrigado pelas sugestões !

Answer (score 2):

Use o `nomeDoElemento.click()`.

`inputExc.click(nomeDaFunção)` ou pode criar uma função:

```
inputExc.click(function(){
})
```

Comment: Teste esse método e a função é executada assim que esse elemento é criado, e não quando clico sobre ele.

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar o **addEventListener**

```
inputExc.addEventListener("click", function(){
});
```